# Determine if returned output from server is stderr or stdout on client in Meteor/Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, meteor, stdout

I run exec command given by user and return it's output to client. Everything works fine when I return just result, but I need to run two different if scenarios, based on stdout and stderr. How to determine if returned output is stdout or stderr? In this scenario it always runs like stdout.*

*I need direct solution, want to avoid using collections. Note this is just example code.

SERVER:

```js
// load future from fibers
var Future = Meteor.npmRequire("fibers/future");
// load exec
var exec = Meteor.npmRequire("child_process").exec;

Meteor.methods({
  'command' : function(line) {
    // this method call won't return immediately, it will wait for the
    // asynchronous code to finish, call unblock to allow this client
    this.unblock();
    var future = new Future();
    exec(line, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
      if(stdout){
        console.log(stdout);
        future.return(stdout);
      } else {
        console.log(stderr);
        future.return(stderr);
      }
    });
    return future.wait();
  }
});
```

CLIENT:

```js
var line = inputdl.value;

Meteor.call('command', line, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
  if(stdout){
    console.log(stdout);
  } else {
    alert('Not valid command: ' + stderr); 
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you want to check if the child process exit normally? In this case, you should use `spawn()` which gives `close` event to get the exit code. Non-zero exit code indicates abnormal exit and you should read stderr then.

Comment: can you elaborate? on the server it seems pretty clear what's stdout and stderr. Maybe you just want to use `future.return({stdout: stdout, stderr: stderr});` as the exec callback function body?

Comment: @ChristianFritz Exactly, thank you. Can't believe I forgot about that.

Comment: ok great. I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return an object containing both stdout and stderr:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'command' : function(line) {
    this.unblock();
    var future = new Future();
    exec(line, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
       future.return({stdout: stdout, stderr: stderr});
    });
    return future.wait();
  }
});
```

and on the client:

```
Meteor.call('command', line, function(error, result) {
  if(result.stdout){
    console.log(result.stdout);
  } else {
    alert('Not valid command: ' + result.stderr); 
  }
});
```